# Reconciling two definitions of a differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I am studying differential geometry and I'm still working fully understanding what a differential form is. I have consulted numerous textbooks and posts on this website, and what I find most often are the following two definitions of a $k$-form. For simplicity let's frame all this in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

1. A $k$-form is a function $\omega$ that assigns to each point $p \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a $k$-linear alternating function $\omega_p$ that is defined on the tangent space $T_p \mathbb{R}^n$. In other words, a differential $k$-form $\omega$ is the following function:
   $$\omega: U \rightarrow A_k(T_p \mathbb{R}^n)\\
   p \mapsto \omega_p, \quad \omega_p: T_p \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$
2. A $k$-form $\omega$ is an alternating function such that
   $$\omega: T_p\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$

Let me point out a few differences. The first definition is specific to a point $p$, the second is not. The first definition takes a $k$-form to be a function that assigns another function (that is alternating and maps to a scalar field) to each point $p$, in contrast the second definition directly defines a $k$-form to be this $k$-linear alternating functional.

A few posts on here offer a geometric picture behind differential forms, such as $dx$ being the projection onto the $x$ coordinate, or that if $n$ vectors are fed into a $n$-form, it will spit out some scaled version of the volume of the parallelepiped in $n$-dimensions. These all suggest that definition 2 is correct, but it is definition 1 that I see more often in textbooks.

Which one is correct?

Comment: its not right. A $k$-form is a map such that for each $p\in U$ it defines a multilinear function $\omega|_p : (T_p M )^k \to \mathbb{R}$, such that the multilinear function is alternating

Comment: @Masacroso Which one is not right, I assume you mean the second definition?

Comment: @Masacroso Also, is there any special name for the function $\omega_p$?

Comment: it will be of much help for you if you can read some chapters of the second edition of *Introduction to smooth manifolds* of John Lee. In short: a differential $k$-form over a manifold $M$ its a section of the power bundle $\bigwedge^k (T^* M)$

Comment: @Masacroso I have been using that book as a reference to my main book which is *Introduction to Manifolds* by Tu, which starts off by defining differential forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ before getting into the full generality of manifolds and bundles. Maybe this is the root of my confusion.

Comment: The second is just all wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see, so is the first correct?

Comment: Even the first is not right. You have a $p$ in the codomain of $\omega$ which is wrong. And to say $\omega_p\colon T_p\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ is misleading, because it needs $k$ vectors as its input. For $p\in U$, $\omega_p\in A_k(T_p\Bbb R^n)$. If you're stuck on the basic definitions, you might find browsing through my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile) on differential forms helpful.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, I will watch your lecture. By the way, you have some of the nicest handwriting I have seen on a chalkboard!